# asp:UploadFile aceptar sólo archivo excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Me gustaría agregar robustez al siguiente código para subir un archivo en un Sitio Web ASP.NET C#. Entre ellas sólo aceptar archivos de Excel .xls o .xlsx

```
protected void btnAgregarArchivoExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string mensaje = "";
    if (cotrolFileUpload.HasFile) {
        try {
            cotrolFileUpload.SaveAs(MapPath("~/Archivos/" + cotrolFileUpload.FileName.ToString()));
            mensaje = "<p>Archivo cargado con éxito.</p>";
            ltEstadoSubida.Text = "<div class='alert alert-success'>" + mensaje + "</div>";
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ltEstadoSubida.Text = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>" + ex.Message + "</div>";
        }
    } else {
        mensaje = "<p>Primero debe cargar el archivo.</p>";
        ltEstadoSubida.Text = "<div class='alert alert-warning'>" + mensaje + "</div>";
    }
}
```

En algunas páginas utilizan la opción ContentType y otros leen después del "punto" pero no he encontrado una opción que me permita eso.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes preguntar por la extension del archivo antes de guardarlo:

```
var extensionesPermitidas = new String[]{ ".xls", ".xlsx" };

if (cotrolFileUpload.HasFile) {

  var fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(cotrolFileUpload.FileName).ToLower();

  if(extensionesPermitidas.Contains(fileExtension) == false)
  {  
    ltEstadoSubida.Text = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Solo archivos excel son permitidos</div>";
  }
  else{
    // ...
   }
}
else{
//..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

También puedes validar del lado del cliente antes de enviarlo al lado del servidor usando RegularExpressionValidator si el campo es obligatorio usas RequiredFieldValidator.

```
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegExValFileUploadFileType" runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="FileUpload1"
        ErrorMessage="Solo archivos xls o xlsx" Font-Bold="True"
        Font-Size="Medium"
        ForeColor="Red"
        ValidationGroup="ValidarArchivo"
        ValidationExpression="(.*?)\.(xls|xlsx)$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

    <asp:Button ID="btnAgregarArchivoExcel" runat="server" Text="Agregar Archivo Excel" ValidationGroup="ValidarArchivo" OnClick="btnAgregarArchivoExcel_Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Usar un FileDialog?

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.FilterIndex = 0;
        dialog.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xlsx;*.xls)|*.xlsx;*.xls";
        DialogResult res = dialog.ShowDialog();

        if (res == DialogResult.OK)
        {       
             //Tu codigo aqui

        }
```